# Two AppStore Accounts With The Same Name. I got codeSign error 'Name' appears more than once in the keychain

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store

I got another new account for the AppStore, I setup the new account certificates on my MAC. Now when I try to publish XCode gives me the error

CodeSign error: Certificate identity 'iPhone Distribution: 'Name' appears more than once in the keychain. The codesign tool requires there only be one.

How can I change my certificate identity for the other account? While I have to leave my Name as it is on both itunes profiles.
How can avoid this problem without have to remove one certificate each time I need to publish app on appstore.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I create a keychain for each team, and put all the related files (public key, private key, certificate) for the team in the keychain.  The only downside is that you have to set your default keychain to the team keychain when building for a device.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore with XCode 4.4 since it searches all keychains.  I had to delete all my other distribution certificates for the account I was not actively building for.  I also had to delete all provisioning profiles associated with that account out of organizer

Answer (score 12):

Look in the keychain app on your Mac. You may have expired entries as well as current entries.  Delete the expired entries and you will be okay.  Worked for me today.

Comment: I really have another account on AppStore, it is not matter of conflict.

Answer (score 1):

I have just had this problem, and my current temporary solution was to export then delete one of the distribution identities, leaving me with one identity which then XCode is happy with. So I will have to export, delete, and import each time I want to switch to a different project to make a distribution, which isn't ideal.

I am still looking for a nicer solution.

The keychain approach sounds ok in principle, but in practice it appears to be require using the "Reset the default keychain" option in Keychain Preferences, which I have not tried yet but doesn't sound like a low-risk activity.

Comment: thanks, that should help me a lot - i'm using the setup on a build server, so switching the keychains is more or less a breeze

Answer (score 0):

I did publish multiple apps on multiple app store accounts using multiple certificate (for the same identity, aka "me") and Xcode manages to understand which certificate to use for which app so far (i may have to help him out by selecting the correct provisionning profile manually from time to time in the "project info" menu).

What i'm doing is to create a new certificate for every new "app store" account i'm working on, and of course never collide the app ids. That means my keychain is full of "iPhone developer - Ben (XDFUHSD)", "iPhone developer - Ben (DSUKJNSD)", etc... certificates, each beeing used for a different client.

Xcode does give me the error you mention from time to time, but it really only happens when one of my certificate has expired and i've just redownloaded a new one.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I got this error even though there was only one copy of the offending certificate in my keychain. The only odd thing about my setup was I'd added the keychain file from my 10.6 partition into Keychain Access, so I had two "login" keychains. Even though the other one didn't any certificates in it at all, the "appears more than once" error went away when I removed it from Keychain Access.

On the plus side, Automatic Provisioning seems to work pretty well these days, so clearing and reloading all my profiles wasn't the nightmare I'd thought it would be..